# Compressing list[0], list[1], list[2],... into a simple statement

Tags: python, list

I have a few situations where i am taking a list of raw data and am passing it into a class. At present it looks something like this:

```
x = Classname(
    listname[0],
    listname[1],
    listname[2],
    listname[3],
    listname[4],
    listname[5],
    listname[6],
    listname[7],
    ...

)
```

and so on. This is quite long and frustrating to read, especially when i am doing it multiple times in the same file, so i was wondering if there was a simpler way to write this? Something to the effect of:

```
x = Classname(
    # item for item in list
)
```

Any help would be appreciated, my brain is fried.
Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unpack the list with the `*args` notation.

```
x = Classname(*listname)
```

Comment: I cannot believe it's that simple. Will accept the answer asap. Cheers mate!

Comment: @Parakiwi Python is pretty awesome.

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
listname = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

class Classname:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        print(args)

x = Classname(*listname)
```